# Powershell Command post-build VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell

I have a command in my post-build event command line in Visual Studio 2010

`Powershell -command .'$(SolutionDir)Powershell\MoveFiles.ps1'`

And when the event runs, I get an error that the command "exited with code 1."

However when I run the same command on the command line (see below), with an actual directory instead of the VS2010 macro, it works perfectly.

`Powershell -command .'C:\TFS\MyProject\Main\Source\Powershell\MoveFiles.ps1'`

So it seems that the problem lies with how VS2010 is executing the command.

What could be causing this problem?

[UPDATE]

I have also tried changing the post-build event to:

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell -command .'C:\TFS\MyProject\Main\Source\Powershell\MoveFiles.ps1'` and I get the same result as described above. It works when run from the command line but not from VS 2010.

Comment: The same result: as in working perfectly, or giving you a error?

Comment: In Visual Studio build and get the error. Then select "View" from the top menu and select "Output". The output window will come up. Examine the content in the window and if the reason is still unclear, please post the output here. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1. Use the `-file` parameter instead of the `-command` parameter.
2. Use double quotes.

`powershell.exe -file "$(SolutionDir)Powershell\MoveFiles.ps1"`

Answer (score 3):

If you are running on a 64-bit OS, you will need to specify the full path to the 64-bit version of powershell since Visual Studio is a 32-bit app.

There is an answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006619/call-powershell-script-in-post-built-with-parameters) that has a workaround for the problem.